# ¿Cómo recuperar el rol de usuario en laravel?

Tags: laravel, spatie, laravel-permission

hago la siguiente consulta

```
$usuario = auth()->user();
```

me devuelve esto:

```
{"id":1,"name":"admin","email":"admin@gmail.com","email_verified_at":null,"oficina":"Iz\u00facar De Matamoros","created_at":"2022-06-10T18:39:31.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-06-10T18:39:31.000000Z","permissions":[],"roles":[{"id":1,"name":"Administrador","guard_name":"web","created_at":"2022-06-10T18:40:10.000000Z","updated_at":"2022-06-10T18:40:10.000000Z","pivot":{"model_id":1,"role_id":1,"model_type":"App\\Models\\User"}}]}
```

Necesito obtener el name que esta dentro de roles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roles es un array de objetos, puede tener varias roles.

En PHP seria así para obtener todos los nombres de las roles de ese usuario:

```
$usuario = auth()->user();
foreach($usuario->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->name;
}
```

Ya nos dirás si te sirve.